# What spatial clustering algorithm to use to create homogeneous regions from buildings?

Tags: clustering, spatial

I'm really new to clustering and would highly appreciate an advice in which direction I should go. I have data on buildings for an entire city and in addition many locational variables like distance to amenities or air quality. My aim is to cluster buildings that are located geographically close together and which have complementary characteristics. I don't want to use historically defined spatial units such as zip codes or districts bur rather define regions using the underlying data. Is there an approach/algorithm or some literature you could suggest?